# How to return 2d char array (char double pointer) in C?

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, calloc, double-pointer

I am reading a file that contains several lines of strings(max length 50 characters). To store those strings I created a char double-pointer using calloc. The way my code works is as it finds a line in the file it adds one new row (char *) and 50 columns (char) and then stores the value.

My understanding is that I can call this method and get this pointer with values in return. However, I was not getting the values so I check where I am losing it and I found that the memory is not persisting after **while** loop. I am able to print strings using **print 1** statement but **print 2** gives me null.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

```
char **read_file(char *file)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(file, "r");
    char line[50] = {0};
    char **values = NULL;
    int index = 0;
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        perror("Unable to open file!");
        exit(1);
    }

    // read both sequence
    while (fgets(line, 50, fp))
    {
        values = (char **)calloc(index + 1, sizeof(char *));
        values[index] = (char *)calloc(50, sizeof(char));
        values[index] = line;
        printf("%s",values[index]); // print 1
        index++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("%s", values[0]); // print 2
    return values;
}
```

Comment: `values = (char **)calloc(index + 1, sizeof(char *))` needs to be `values = realloc(values, (index + 1)  * sizeof(char *))`

Comment: And if the input file can be empty, then your `printf` before the `return` is going to manifest undefined behavior.

Comment: A much more elegant and faster solution is easy to implement if you don't want to keep the newline for each line that is read. And if that's the case, then the solution won't be encumbered by the 50 character limit.

Comment: Thanks @JeffHolt missing realloc was the problem. I found one more mistake in my code, instead of `values[index] = line;` I should be using `strcpy(values[index], line);`

Comment: Understand `char **values` and the return from `char **read_file()` have absolutely nothing to do with arrays. A `type **var` is a *pointer-to-pointer-to* `type`. You are correct in your thinking about how you can use it and how you can return it, but when you `calloc()` you overwrite the address held by `values` every iteration. You need to `realloc()` (using a temporary pointer) and on successful `realloc()` assign the reallocated block of memory from your temporary pointer to `values`. Further, reallocating every iteration isn't very efficient. Better to allocate a block of pointers.

Answer (score 1):

1. `line` content is overwritten on each loop iteration (by `fgets()`).
2. `values` is overwritten (data loss) and leaks memory on each iteration `index > 1`.
3. `value[index]` is allocated memory on each iteration which leaks as you overwrite it with the address of `line` on the following line.
4. `line` is a local variable so you cannot return it to caller where it will be out of scope.
5. caller has no way to tell how many entries `values` contain.

Here is a working implementation with a few changes.  On error it closes the file and frees up memory allocated and return NULL instead of exiting.  Moved `printf()` to caller:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUF_LEN 50

char **read_file(char *file) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(file, "r");
    if(!fp) {
        perror("Unable to open file!");
        return NULL;
    }
    char **values = NULL;
    char line[BUF_LEN];
    unsigned index;
    for(index = 0;; index++) {
        char **values2 = realloc(values, (index + 1) * sizeof(char *));
        if(!values2) {
            perror("realloc failed");
            goto err;
        }
        values = values2;
        if(!fgets(line, BUF_LEN, fp)) break;
        values[index] = strdup(line);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    values[index] = NULL;
    return values;
err:
    fclose(fp);
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        free(values[i]);
    }
    free(values);
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    char **values = read_file("test.txt");
    for(unsigned i = 0; values[i]; i++) {
        printf("%s", values[i]);
        free(values[i]);
    }
    free(values);
    return 0;
}
```

`fgets()` returns line ending in '\n' or at most BUF_LEN - 1 of data.  This means a given `value[i]` may or may not be ending with a `\n`.  You may want this behavior, or you want `value[i]` to be consistent and not contain any trailing `\n` irregardless of the input.

`strdup()` is `_POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200809L` and not standard c,
so if you build with `--std=c11` the symbol would not be defined.

Comment: May want a `line[strcspn (line, "\n")] = 0;` after `fgets(line, BUF_LEN, fp)` and before `values[index] = strdup(line);` to trim the `'\n'` from the end of `line` before it is stored so you don't have `'\n'`s dangling off the end of each string.  Also, if `realloc()` fails, you can `return values;` at that point as all data up to that point in `values` is still valid. You can check `if (index)` to determine if there is valid data to preserve. (up to you) Rest looks good.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yeah, I thought about the first part, but it is not clear what behavior op was looking for.  Please leave your comment around till op responds, and I will revise code if needed.  On 2nd part, I `goto err;` and return NULL if realloc fails and cleanup whatever data was allocated so far.  What am I missing?

Comment: When `realloc()` fails it returns `NULL` and does NOT free `values` -- and since you are a wise programmer reallocating with the temporary pointer `values2`, the memory pointed to by `values` is untouched and remains valid. It's your choice, but `if (index)` then you have valid data stored at each `index` in `values` -- so you have the choice of `return values;` to return the data up to the point of failure. (that is another primary benefit of reallocating with a temporary pointer) or do as you do, clean up and `free()` all at that point. Completely up to you, but worth considering.

Comment: Another "worth mentioning" is `strdup()` is POSIX and not Standard C. So if compiling with, e.g. `-std=c11` it will not find `strdup()` without a defined macro like, e.g. `_GNU_SOURCE`. Unless compiling to a strict standard, most compilers will have `strdup()` available -- so it's just very small worth mentioning.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yeah, and my choice was to be "transactional" and free both values[i] and values if realloc fails.  I totally get your point that everything was valid up to that point, and you could return it, but I think it would be tricky for caller to deal with "here is some data, it may or may not be a the first part or many".  You could return something to say it's a partial failure and to retry but that just needs to complicate this further with little benefit.  Thanks.  I will add your suggest re `strdup()`.

Comment: Yep, that covers all bases and it is a valid choice either way. The value in the discussion is helping the OP and others think through that decision-tree which helps cement how `realloc()` works.