# Trying to use the strtok function to make sub strings and store into arrays

Tags: arrays, c, string, parsing

I am wanting to take in an input from a string, then go through each line and parse the line into sub strings by splitting using spaces. I have a while loop nested in a while loop to try and get this work. When I print the char* in the loop I get the expected output, but once exiting the loop and then printing different position I get unexpected values.

```
while ((getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1){
    //line is an array of characters
    //piece is a char pointer that stores the sub strings of a line
    //where a string is broken into sub strings by a space
    char *piece = strtok(line, " ");
    while(piece != NULL){
      tokens[j] = piece;
      printf("%s\n", tokens[j]);
      piece = strtok(NULL, " ");
      j++;
    }
  }
  printf("%s\n", tokens[0]);
```

Comment: Please update your code with a [mre].

Comment: You are loading new lines of data to the same buffer, thus overriding previous values.

Comment: This: `tokens[j] = piece;` assigns to an element of `tokens` the address of part of the `line` buffer. But then, in the next outer loop, you overwrite that buffer with new input, so your previously-saved pointers, though still referring to the same location, point to different data than on the previous loop.

Comment: ... something like `tokens[j] = strdup(piece);` would probably work. But then you'd need to run through all the tokens and `free()` them, when you're finished. But this is a duplicate, for sure ...

Comment: Possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61414715/10871073 (That's one I answered, and it's maybe not the best.)

Comment: What do you mean by I am "loading new lines of data to the same buffer, thus overriding previous values"?

Comment: Here: `getline(&line, &len, fp)`.

Comment: Oh, so does getline() cause the memory that my tokens array is at to change values of which the memory holds?

Comment: So basically the array is pointing to the same address but each time I call getline() I am getting new information that is replacing past information in the memory?

Comment: Let's say `line="bob jane"` so when you call `strtok()` the 2nd time, it returns `&line[4]` which is "jane".  Then you read a new line, so the value stored in the array changes to say `line="michelle"` and now your previous `&line[4]` will point to "elle" which is not what you expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to not overwrite `line` (per @AdrianMole) for instance by `realloc(line, new_larger_size)` so it can hold your entire input, or copy each token and subsequently free the memory allocated with for example `strdup()`:

```
tokens[j] = strdup(piece);
...
// cleanup: assumes last tokens[i] is NULL.  If tokens itself is heap allocated you need to free it too
for(int i = 0; tokens[i]; i++) free(tokens[j]);
```

I answered a somewhat similar question yesterday: [How to return 2d char array (char double pointer) in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71962893/how-to-return-2d-char-array-char-double-pointer-in-c/71962953#71962953)

Comment: Maybe voting to close as a duplicate is better than 'repeating' one of your own answers?

Comment: @AdrianMole Similar to how you felt about your answer it's not an exact duplicate.

Comment: I understand.  But, once closed, better duplicates can be found and the list in the blue banner can be edited.

Comment: @AdrianMole It's a fine resolution.  Btw, how do you edit the list of duplicates after it's closed?  I didn't know that was an option.

Comment: You need a "gold tag badge" in one of the question's tags (or a moderator's diamond) to be able to edit the list. If you (or anyone else without that access) finds a better duplicate, feel free to @-ping me.